# Looking Time windows for 24 Hr interval

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am executing below query in SQL Server 2012

```
print dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,getdate()),0)
print dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0)
```

and getting below result

```
Nov  9 2017 12:00AM
Nov 10 2017 12:00AM
```

But i am looking result like below

```
Nov  9 2017 12:00AM
Nov  10 2017 11:59PM
```

Please help !!

Answer (score 1):

You would seem to want:

```
print cast(getdate() as date);
print dateadd(minute, -1, dateadd(day, 2, cast(getdate() as date)))
```

Or, alternatively:

```
print cast(getdate() as date);
print dateadd(minute, 2*24*60-1, cast(getdate() as date))
```

Comment: Excellent !! Thank you.